# How to center a table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to put a centered table below the title, instead i get a right handed alignment.
I tried `\begin{center}` instead of `\begin{table}`, i get the same result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lineno}


\begin{document}

\title{Title:\\ more title}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
\textsc{column 1}   & \textsc{column 2}              & \textsc{column 3}& 
\textsc{column 4}        \\ \hline
something here      & something more here            & something here a     & something here           \\
something here      & something here                 & Rsomething more here & something here           \\
something here      & something here /something here & something here n     & something more here      \\
something more here & something more here            & something here       & something more here more \\
something here      & something here                 &                      & something here
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result: right alignment]

Comment: Your table is centered, most likely, it's just too wide to fit on the page and leaks into the right margin. There should be some `overfull box` warnings, I assume

Comment: to see page layout (and that table is to wide) just add `\usepackage{showframe}` to your document's preamble. As solution you can determine wide text width (with package `geometry` for example) or limit table width to text width and allow that cells' contents be in more lines.

Comment: So, i can "center it" just erasing a column?  There must be another way to do it, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is too large for the available text width, see Christian Hupfer's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375474/how-to-center-a-table-in-latex#comment929130_375474).

A suggestion:

- `X` columns of `tabularx` are similar to `p` columns, but use the available space automatically without explicit dimension. Only the table gets a width.
- `\midrule` of package `booktabs` for a nicer rule with proper vertical white space around.
- `\RaggedRight` of package `ragged2e` to get a smoother `\raggedright` by allowing hyphenation.
- `\hangindent=1em\hangafter1\relax` for indentation of the follow-up lines in the cells' first paragraph.
- `\slash` instead of `/` for a slash with break point.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lineno}


\begin{document}

\title{Title:\\ more title}
\maketitle

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{>{\hangindent=1em\hangafter=1\RaggedRight}X}}
\textsc{column 1}   & \textsc{column 2}              & \textsc{column 3}&
\textsc{column 4}        \\ \midrule
something here      & something more here            & something here a     & something here           \\
something here      & something here                 & Rsomething more here & something here           \\
something here      & something here\slash something here & something here  & something more here      \\
something more here & something more here            & something here       & something more here more \\
something here      & something here                 &                      & something here
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]